# No history and path/bash completion on some systems

Tags: bash, auto-completion, bash-history

For some reason, I don't have a history of commands in the terminal and neither can I complete paths or commands. Pressing arrows also show symbols like `^[[D` and `^[[C`.

The shell is bash and .bashrc exists with the necessary autocompletion config.

Results of some outputs:

```
echo $SHELL: /bin/bash
echo $PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
echo $HISTFILE: 
echo $HISTSIZE: 
echo $HISTFILESIZE: 
echo $TERM: xterm-256color
```

Also my username and pwd aren't shown before the `$` or `#`.

Comment: How did you determine that the shell is bash? what is the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: Also of interest `echo $SHELL;echo $PATH;echo $HISTFILE;echo $HISTSIZE;echo $HISTFILESIZE;echo $TERM`. Remember to Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1212119/edit ) your Question to add the information, DO NOT add it in comments.

Comment: @steeldriver by using `echo $SHELL`.  Result of your command is the same: `/bin/bash`

Comment: @waltinator Added as requested

Comment: Have you messed with any readline-related shell options? what is the output of `set +o | grep -w 'vi\|emacs'`?

Comment: @steeldriver `set +o vi` and `set +o emacs`

Comment: @EarthMind OK so that likely explains why you have no readline support (including why the arrow keys don't work). The default for interactive bash shells is  `set -o emacs` but AFAIK you need either `vi` or `emacs` set (i.e. one `-o` rather than both `+o`). It *may* explain the lack of history as well - not sure about that.

Comment: @steeldriver It's like this on the other systems as well though, and there history and completion work properly.

Comment: @EarthMind at least as a test, did you try executing `set -o emacs` in the terminal? do the arrow keys start working?

Comment: @steeldriver I did and didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

By not having `HISTFILE` and `HISTSIZE`/`HISTFILEZISE` undefined, you have told `bash` that you don't want history logging.

Here's how I get one logfile for every `bash` procss I run:

From `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -d ~/.history ]] || mkdir --mode=0700 ~/.history
[[ -d ~/.history ]] && chmod 0700 ~/.history
HISTFILE=~/.history/history.$(date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S).$$
# close any old history file by zeroing HISTFILESIZE  
HISTFILESIZE=0  
# then set HISTFILESIZE to a large value
HISTFILESIZE=4096  
HISTSIZE=4096
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it unfortunately. I feel something deeper is responsible which makes all of the above issues appear

Comment: This does not explain why the control sequences are not being recognized as cursor keys, stated in the second sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have run, and are currently talking to, the Debian Almquist shell.  All of the symptoms match:

- prompt is `$`
- no cursor key control sequence recognition
- `+o vi` and `+o emacs` in the output of `set -o`
- no change in response to `set -o emacs`

The Almquist shell *can* have line editing.  The FreeBSD Almquist shell has it, as does the BusyBox Almquist shell.  The *Debian* Almquist shell lacks it, it not being compiled in.  The *Debian* Almquist shell is deliberately minimal on Ubuntu (and Debian) as about a decade and a half ago Ubuntu and Debian switched `/bin/sh` over to it, resulting in a significant speedup to many system scripts, precisely *because* this shell lacked the bells and whistles of other shells.

If you invoked it by running `sh`, which seems most likely given the value of the `SHELL` environment variable, `exit` that shell to be back to your original Bourne Again shell.

## Further reading

- [*DashAsBinSh*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).  2007.  Ubuntu wiki.